# Not able to find the locator in cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

Trying to figure out how can i find the locator in cypress: I am trying to find the locator for Select a venue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DroOX.png)

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="0ecd2cea-d327-4c15-bdb0-591619f4674c" value="" style="padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 100%; border: none; outline: none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); cursor: inherit; font: inherit; opacity: 1; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); height: 100%;">
```

here is my html code:

```
    <span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">Select a Venue</span>

I am not able to use id because it is dynamic.In selenium there is a way to do it going from parent to child element. How can i do similar in cypress? for example - finding the span text = Select a venue then finding its text box


Here is the full html code:

<div class="jss295"><div class="jss277"><div class="" style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: row;"><div class="jss278" style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column;"><div class="jss66"><label class="jss302 jss296 jss297 jss300 jss299" data-shrink="true" for="5afa951b-7e02-4e0b-a446-e3e09b355825">First Name</label><div class="jss201 jss202"><input class="jss210 jss213" id="5afa951b-7e02-4e0b-a446-e3e09b355825" name="firstName" type="text" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false" value="" style="padding: 8px;"></div></div></div><div class="jss278" style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column;"><div class="jss66"><label class="jss302 jss296 jss297 jss300 jss299" data-shrink="true" for="17b2fe19-df71-4da3-b095-44c23a3bb7df">Last Name</label><div class="jss201 jss202"><input class="jss210 jss213" id="17b2fe19-df71-4da3-b095-44c23a3bb7df" name="lastName" type="text" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false" value="" style="padding: 8px;"></div></div></div></div><div class="jss278" style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column;"><div class="jss66"><label class="jss302 jss296 jss297 jss300 jss299" data-shrink="true" for="2242035f-7235-4e4d-90c8-5ebd26c09452">Email</label><div class="jss201 jss202"><input class="jss210 jss213" id="2242035f-7235-4e4d-90c8-5ebd26c09452" name="email" type="text" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false" value="" style="padding: 8px;"></div></div></div><div class="" style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin-right: 16px; margin-bottom: 24px;"><div class="mui-select"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">Select a Venue</span><div style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; width: 100%; display: inline-block; position: relative; background-color: transparent; font-family: Helvetica, &quot;Open Sans&quot;; transition: height 200ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; cursor: text; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid rgb(229, 230, 235); margin-bottom: 36px; padding-bottom: 8px; margin-top: 8px;"><div><div style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div style="display: flex; position: relative; width: 256px; padding: 0px 8px; margin: 0px; font: inherit; height: 32px; border: none; outline: none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); cursor: initial; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); float: left; min-height: 32px; flex-wrap: nowrap;"><div style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; width: 256px; height: 48px; display: inline-block; position: relative; background-color: transparent; font-family: Helvetica, &quot;Open Sans&quot;; transition: height 200ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; cursor: auto;"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="8d0b19a8-7d46-46f5-b520-3cadb79c305b" value="" style="padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 100%; border: none; outline: none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); cursor: inherit; font: inherit; opacity: 1; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); height: 100%;"></div><div style="display: none;"></div></div><div><hr aria-hidden="true" style="border-top: none rgb(224, 224, 224); border-left: none rgb(224, 224, 224); border-right: none rgb(224, 224, 224); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); bottom: 8px; box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%; display: none;"><hr aria-hidden="true" style="border-top: none rgb(74, 193, 192); border-left: none rgb(74, 193, 192); border-right: none rgb(74, 193, 192); border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(74, 193, 192); bottom: 8px; box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%; display: none; transform: scaleX(0); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;"></div></div></div></div><div class="" style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin-right: 16px; margin-bottom: 24px;"><div class="mui-select"><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">Select a brand</span><div style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; width: 100%; display: inline-block; position: relative; background-color: transparent; font-family: Helvetica, &quot;Open Sans&quot;; transition: height 200ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; cursor: text; border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid rgb(229, 230, 235); margin-bottom: 36px; padding-bottom: 8px; margin-top: 8px;"><div><div style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div style="display: flex; position: relative; width: 256px; padding: 0px 8px; margin: 0px; font: inherit; height: 32px; border: none; outline: none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); cursor: initial; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); float: left; min-height: 32px; flex-wrap: nowrap;"><div style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; width: 256px; height: 48px; display: inline-block; position: relative; background-color: transparent; font-family: Helvetica, &quot;Open Sans&quot;; transition: height 200ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; cursor: auto;"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="0e376717-85ff-4cf7-b7c5-e795b5d100fe" value="" style="padding: 0px; position: relative; width: 100%; border: none; outline: none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); cursor: inherit; font: inherit; opacity: 1; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); height: 100%;"></div><div style="display: none;"></div></div><div><hr aria-hidden="true" style="border-top: none rgb(224, 224, 224); border-left: none rgb(224, 224, 224); border-right: none rgb(224, 224, 224); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); bottom: 8px; box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%; display: none;"><hr aria-hidden="true" style="border-top: none rgb(74, 193, 192); border-left: none rgb(74, 193, 192); border-right: none rgb(74, 193, 192); border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(74, 193, 192); bottom: 8px; box-sizing: content-box; margin: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%; display: none; transform: scaleX(0); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;"></div></div></div></div><div class="jss278" style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column;"><label class="jss306"><span class="jss96 jss317 jss312 jss314 jss309"><span class="jss323"><svg class="jss216 jss324" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg><input type="checkbox" class="jss313" value=""></span></span><span class="jss120 jss129 jss308">Read only</span></label></div><div class="" style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-end; align-items: flex-end; padding-right: 16px;"><button tabindex="-1" class="jss96 jss97 jss144 jss150 jss156 f1j6pgoy" type="button" disabled=""><span class="jss146"><p class="jss120 jss129 fitb9kk">Add User</p></span></button></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the html code instead of a picture?

Comment: @DiogoRocha, i have updated my question, can you please take a look

Comment: Post HTML for the whole form please.

Comment: @dwelle, i added full html form

Comment: looking at the HTML, there's nothing you can do other than selecting by offsets (nth-element and children). If you can modify the HTML, sprinkle in classes or `data-test` handles (etc.) --- which you can remove on build.

Comment: @dwelle, any example that can help? not sure how i can do that in cypress

Comment: @CCC not in cypress - you should add the classes in your source HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cy.get` to find the input by the id value. So for the sample input you provided, you could use:

```
cy.get('#0ecd2cea-d327-4c15-bdb0-591619f4674c')
```

and continue on your testing. If that id value was determined dynamically, you could just give it a class value (e.g., `class="venue-input"`) and use

```
cy.get('.venue-input')
```

For more info on selecting text inputs, you can also [review this video](https://vimeo.com/240554808).

Comment: unfortuantely the id is dynamic

Comment: Can you try to add the class as suggested above?

Comment: it is giving this error - CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected '[ <input#undefined-undefined-Selectavenue-48914>, 13 more... ]' to have text 'Select a Venue', but the text was ''